# Error in Concatenating N- number of arraylist each of dimension d in java

Tags: java, debugging, arraylist

I want to concatenate N- number of d-dimensional arraylist into one large arraylist . I have done following:

```
 {
     Arraylist<Double> cFeature = new Arraylist<Double>(); 
     for(int i =0 ; i < n; i++){
        ArrayList<Double> arrList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        arrList = FeatureMatrix.get(i);
        cFeature.addAll(arrList);
     }  
    return cFeature;
}
```

But this is not returning me concatenated feature vector. What can be the reason for it?

I have matrix of  following type

```
    1 2 3 4
    4 5 6 7
    9 4 5 2
```

I want to return  something like:

```
    12344567, 45679452 etc
```

EDIT[Matrix one row],Matrix is of dimension 50

```
   [-1.4707351089135285, -2.396807707665656, -0.9225858560474335, -0.552093667789784, 0.6492206869123566, 1.1347653279780474, 0.18599226559979623, -0.3040490372134513, -0.8661743997164002, 1.2990217001062885, -1.4689261255216413, -0.6175058675322327, 0.0019875740898560707, 3.187991109660048, 0.9793588130569899, 1.88726260031087, 1.263110196592273, 0.10270882950413489, -0.33850097448844163, 0.26780865103769547, -0.28117099016766645, -0.015511886681809741, -0.7906057240014217, 0.1796874905794462, 0.9327631100459427, 0.5419684468033518, 1.3670537985364393, -1.0381888770019032, 1.0975151287297011, 0.024367745998744996, -0.25780912155025204, -1.862325174655491, -0.611104255824939, -0.5746070435381269, -1.2218773341433158, 0.2220916817954159, 0.4641455500389115, -0.43253367269335635, -0.5380163044326588, 0.685592907063921, -0.6191939669845238, -1.2275198581496152, 0.13270110767423787, -0.1614948461888469, 1.5717904793822337, -0.2826323802880358, -0.4716922630198008, -0.2881374794211655, 0.8609910302314909, 1.1749707572533885]
```

Comment: No FeatureMatrix is a matrix containing some large number of d-dimensional arraylist.

Comment: OK, so you could just do `cFeature.addAll(FeatureMatrix.get(i));`. Do you have println statements that allow you to debug this loop to see what variables are actually being passed?

Comment: its hashmap, i will pass index and it will return an arraylist of d elements.

Comment: It would help if you could add the current (wrong) output of your code. I think there is a problem with the `FeatureMatrix.get(i)` method…

Comment: … and it is not clear to me what your expected result is. I think `FeatureMatrix.get(0)` returns the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `FeatureMatrix.get(1)` returns `[4, 5, 6, 7]`, `FeatureMatrix.get(2)` returns `[9, 4, 5, 2]` and your desired result is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 4, 5, 2]`, right?

Comment: Exactly @siegi, that is what i want.

Comment: @thetna: what does your FeatureMatrix look like? It's likely the problem is there.

Comment: @thetna In this case the code you listed is correct, the problem is in some other place. Could you add something like `System.out.println(arrList);` after `arrList = FeatureMatrix.get(i);` as "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" already asked? I really think `FeatureMatrix.get(i)` returns something wrong…

Comment: @siegi, I added it in my question. each row of matrix is of 50 dimnesion and entries are double.

Comment: @thetna Ok, so `FeatureMatrix.get(i)` returns some values and the code above should work. You say "this is not returning me concatenated feature vector". What does it return? Maybe there is an error where you call the code you posted in your question?

Comment: i am getting something weried unexpected large size of concatenated featurevector. **cFeature.size()** returns something very large number , which is not expected at all.

Comment: @thetna This is a very important information ;-) How many rows has your matrix? Note that `cFeature` will have `numberOfColumns*numberOfRows` elements in it. Maybe the `n` you use in the `for` loop is wrong?

Comment: N is small number , its basically a context size of N-gram.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10347/discussion-between-siegi-and-thetna)

Comment: Don't bother working on this question without reading the chat and the pastebin code!!!

Answer (score 1):

You left out critical parts of the code in your question.  Looking at [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3397846) and the [full code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/W1SwiqgN) it seems to me the problem is that you don't understand how assignment works in Java (perhaps you have a C++ background?)

```
    ArrayList<Double> contextFeature = new ArrayList<Double>();
    contextFeature = wordFeatureMatrix.get(x); // x is a valid integer key, actually FrequentWordIndex.get(Ngram.get(0).toLowerCase()) in the pastebin code
```

This destroys the original ArrayList you created for contextFeature and replaces it with one of the ArrayLists in wordFeatureMatrix.

Then later you are iterating not over `wordFeatureMatrix` but rather a list that is returning indexes into wordFeatureMatrix.  I'm confident that at some point

```
wordFeatureMatrix.get(FrequentWordIndex.get(Ngram.get(0).toLowerCase())) ==
    wordFeatureMatrix.get(FrequentWordIndex.get(Ngram.get(i).toLowerCase()));
```

Which means later you are essentially calling

```
 contextFeature.addAll(contextFeature);
```

From the JavaDoc for `ArrayList.addAll()`:

> The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified Collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified Collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)

So, you have two problems. The first is not to modify `wordFeatureMatrix` in the process of collecting the `contextFeature` list, to which the solution is to replace

```
    ArrayList<Double> contextFeature = new ArrayList<Double>();
    contextFeature = wordFeatureMatrix.get(x);
```

with

```
    ArrayList<Double> contextFeature = new ArrayList<Double>();
    contextFeature.addAll(wordFeatureMatrix.get(x));
```

The second problem, which may not be a problem in your use case, is to make sure that the same list doesn't get added twice.  That's up to you to decide if it's what you want or not.